# Unable to Connect to Box API in R

Tags: r, api, box

all. I am trying to set up boxr to read files from Box's API.

The set up seems pretty simple. I created a Box app. I then copy/pasted the client secret and client ID into `box_auth()`

```
library(boxr)
box_auth(client_id = "<placeholder>", client_secret = "<placeholder>")
```

When I do this I am taken to a new page that says:

```
There seems to be a problem with this app. 

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
```

Because there are so few steps, I am a little lost on what could be going wrong.

Advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this same issue after months of `boxr` working as expected - the steps and explanation [outlined here](https://github.com/r-box/boxr/issues/230) resolved the issue on my end.

Going to the dev console for your Box account, and then to the "Configuration" tab, add `http://localhost:1410/` as a Redirect URI:

[image]